# Kubernetes pod logs retention

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have joined a project where we deploy our apps on Azure cloud. The apps are in docker containers orchestrated by kubernetes.

We get the data from a POD log file with this command (YAML code below)

kubectl logs --namespace=app-prod 
deployment/app-fd-prod 
> $(logFile)

where logFile is a variable

Now the problem is, yesterday the log file was 27MB. Today the log file is 2MB that means the old data got deleted some how.

I have read about logRotate but i dont think we have implemented that.

I want to know what can be the reason of deletion of yesterday's log file text ?

Any leads, helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Rotated out every hour above 10MB or daily. You're expected to consume the logs using some aggregation. The popular open source option is fluentd+elasticsearch+kibana, but there are many commercial hosted log providers as well.

Comment: what kubectl command can i use to check the current Rotate config ?

Comment: Docs are here and mentions a setting for CRI-O runtime, but not for docker: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#logging-at-the-node-level

Comment: I repeat my question, what kubectl command can i use to see the current rotate settings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pod logs get rotated for you as pointed out by @jordanm in the comments. You need a log aggregation tool like the ELK/EFK stack (Elastic + Logstash + kibana or Elastic + fluentd + kibana) or Promtail + loki + grafana. These stacks tail the logs of containers, do some fancy parsing / manipulation and ships it to persistent storage like S3.

Side note you can take a look at the [logging operator](https://github.com/banzaicloud/logging-operator) that makes the config of these things a little easier.